# Summing values of a vector after grouping them by another vector

Tags: r

```
x <-  c(1,   2,  2,  3,  3, 3,    4)
Fx <- c(.4, .2, .4, .5, .2, 1.2, .8)
```

So I want to group Fx by values of x and then sum the values in the groups.

It should return:

```
new_x <-  c(1,   2,     3,         4)
new_Fx <- c(.4, .2+.4, .5+.2+1.2, .8)
```

How can I do this in r?

Comment: You need `tapply` i.e. `tapply(Fx, x, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Or `ave(new_x, new_Fx, FUN=sum)` (although that loses the grouping information)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before here: [How to sum a variable by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group).

With your data, you can try this:

```
df <-  data.frame(x=c(1,   2,  2,  3,  3, 3,    4), 
                 Fx = c(.4, .2, .4, .5, .2, 1.2, .8))

df$x <- as.character(df$x)

aggregate(df$Fx, by=list(x = df$x), FUN=sum)
```